# How to prevent rain damage from neighbouring property

Tags: gutters

We've recently moved to a two story detached house which has a neighboring bungalow very close to the border. The property next door doesn't have any guttering which causes all of their rain water to hit the side of our house. I believe it is their responsibility to not do this, but are there any solutions we could do which would prevent any issues with damp penetration? The alleyway between the two properties is less than 1m wide so the solution doesn't have to be attractive. Is there any option to install a splash guard combined with guttering which feeds into our existing down pipe? I can't find anything suitable as a splash guard and my concern is this would just hold the moisture in place.

Comment: And the neighbor isn’t responsive to guttering their roof? That seems like the best option even if you had to pay for/do it. Your options for your house would be ugly and temporary and cost just as much I think, but maybe someone else here has a better idea

Comment: you could run a french drain between the houses. weeds that don't mind shade could help block a lot of the splashing and erosion. if nothing else, i would camp-dri the areas that stay the wettest the longest.